# Does having multiple embeded items effect SEO by leaking PageRank or appearing low quality?

Tags: seo, links, pagerank, embed

For example if I have 300 words and embed 10 videos from YouTube or 10 pins from Pinterest on my page instead of hosting them on my domain.

1. Does my page send away PageRank away through outbound links (embed)?
2. Does embeding a lot of pins or videos make my page a low quality in the eyes of Google?

I will have additional text around embed.

Comment: PageRank.... is so oldschoolz. YouTube increases user experience which in turn increases SEO. Google is not going to punish you for using their services. As long as you have some unique content on the page then they are safe.

Comment: @SimonHayter Please don't say PR is old school, It's actually hurts me, because It very hard for me to connect the whole dots. [Thank you to gary to give me some hope](https://twitter.com/methode/status/829755916895535104) :D

Answer (score 2):

Embedding content on your page from other providers like YouTube and Pinterest won't channel ranking away from your page. What matters is originality and the user experience such as page load times. In your siation based on what you have stated in your question you shouldn't see any negative affect on your ranking.